# Why am I getting this error 'TypeError undefined is not an object...' when including Shopify Linked Product Options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to implement Shopify's Linked Product Options into my store (followed this [tutorial](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/linked-product-options)), they seem to be working fine on the product page but breaking other script (Cart & Quick Shop open but no content) on my index and collection pages.

I'm getting the following error in Safari:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'availableOptions.length')
```

which is referencing this piece of code:

```
var initialValue = selector.val();
  selector.empty();    
  var availableOptions = Shopify.optionsMap[key];
  for (var i=0; i<availableOptions.length; i++) {
    var option = availableOptions[i];
    var newOption = jQuery('<option></option>').val(option).html(option);
    selector.append(newOption);
  }
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to why that might be I would appreciate your input. I'm not great with JS so struggling with this one!

**Update:**

I'm pretty sure this part is defining 'key' - if key is undefined does that mean it cannot find `.single-option-selector`?

```
 switch (selectorIndex) {
case 0:
  var key = 'root';
  var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)');
  break;
case 1:
  var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();
  var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)');
  break;
case 2:
  var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();  
  key += ' / ' + jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)').val();
  var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(2)');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 : Find the error

It means availableOptions is `undefind` So the `Shopify.optionsMap[key]` returns undefined.

You should try this to debug. Is key defined? If Shopify right? Does Shopify.optionsMap exist?

```
console.log(key);
console.log(Shopify);
console.log(Shopify.optionsMap);
console.log(Shopify.optionsMap[key]);
```

#### Step 2: Make it more global

```
var key = '';
var selector = '';
switch (selectorIndex) {
case 0:
  key = 'root';
  selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)');
  break;
case 1:
  key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();
  selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)');
  break;
case 2:
  key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();  
  key += ' / ' + jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)').val();
  selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(2)');
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Would you mind explaining what I need to do to debug, this is all quite new to me. I put that into safari console and it returned the following: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: key` What does that mean?

Comment: I've updated my question with the part of js that I'm sure is defining the variable `key`. Does that mean it can't find `.single-option-selector`?

Comment: Oh I know! Key is only defined IN your switch. Make the key variable a bit more global. So define var key outside the switch and just let `key = 'root';` and others. You also should add a default case to your switch !

Comment: Thanks for this tried implementing it but nothing changing other js is still broken. Any ideas why? Might it help to see all the JS? Thanks again.

Comment: Also still getting the same js error. How could it be undefined if the same script is working perfectly on one page but not on another in the site?

Comment: What is the value of the key?

Comment: `.single-option-selector` is applied to each product variant so sizes and colours. I've copy and pasted the script provided in the tutorial to my timber.js file but something must be conflicting as it doesn't seem to be working on the index page and collection page. Its working fine on the product page but on the index page its breaking other script.

Comment: The key value is undefined, so `Shopify.optionsMap[key];`CANNOT be defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78106/discussion-between-alexis-paques-and-user2498890).